# Kafka streams app is throwing org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ProducerFencedException. What is causing it and how do I fix it?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a kafka streams application (using spring kafka) and a bug got deployed. Somewhere between 15 and 30 minutes it was realized and the change was reverted. Now I am getting the following errors:

```
 [Producer clientId=myapplication-793b3cc4-9baf-4759-8516-649955fad000-StreamThread-2-producer, transactionalId=myapplication-793b3cc4-9baf-4759-8516-649955fad000-2] Transiting to fatal error state due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ProducerFencedException: There is a newer producer with the same transactionalId which fences the current one.
```

and

```
     org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TaskMigratedException: Error encountered sending record to topic myapplication-caliperEvents-changelog for task 0_9 due to:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch.
Written offsets would not be recorded and no more records would be sent since the producer is fenced, indicating the task may be migrated out; it means all tasks belonging to this thread should be migrated.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.recordSendError(RecordCollectorImpl.java:215)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.lambda$send$0(RecordCollectorImpl.java:196)
    at brave.kafka.clients.TracingCallback$DelegateAndFinishSpan.onCompletion(TracingCallback.java:58)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer$InterceptorCallback.onCompletion(KafkaProducer.java:1350)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.completeFutureAndFireCallbacks(ProducerBatch.java:273)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.done(ProducerBatch.java:234)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ProducerBatch.completeExceptionally(ProducerBatch.java:198)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.failBatch(Sender.java:758)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.failBatch(Sender.java:743)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.failBatch(Sender.java:695)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.completeBatch(Sender.java:634)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.lambda$null$1(Sender.java:575)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.lambda$handleProduceResponse$2(Sender.java:562)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.handleProduceResponse(Sender.java:562)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.lambda$sendProduceRequest$5(Sender.java:836)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientResponse.onComplete(ClientResponse.java:109)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.completeResponses(NetworkClient.java:574)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:566)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:328)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:243)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and

```
[Producer clientId=myapplication-793b3cc4-9baf-4759-8516-649955fad000-StreamThread-2-producer, transactionalId=myapplication-793b3cc4-9baf-4759-8516-649955fad000-2] Transiting to abortable error state due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer attempted to produce with an old epoch.
```

my application stores messages from an source topic into a Persistent key value store, then reads from it, forwards it, and deletes it from the store within a punctuator. Since I'm getting these errors, the records aren't being deleted from the store and its just re-processing the events over and over. Any help / insight into this would be greatly appreciated

edit: as a temporary workaround, i disabled exactly once processing, and when i re-enabled it ~8 hours later, things we working again. I'm still confused as to why this happened and why it just works again